# Perl Regex (\d*\.\d{2})

Tags: regex, perl

I have run into a regex in Perl that seems to be giving me problems.  I'm fairly new to Perl - but I don't think that's my problem.

Here is the code:

```
if ($line =~ m/<amount>(\d*\.\d{2})<\//) { $amount = $1; }
```

I'm essentially parsing an XML formatted file for a single tag.  Here is the specific value that I'm trying to parse.

```
<amount>23.00000</amount>
```

Can someone please explain why my regex won't work?

EDIT:  I should mention I'm trying to import the amount as a currency value.  The trailing 3 decimals are useless.

Comment: You are only matching TWO decimal places, where there are 5 in your text

Comment: Do you really have backtick characters in your regexp?

Comment: Sorry, there were no back-ticks in the actual regex.  For some reason the site was ignoring <amount> in my "code" so I put those in.

Comment: @Rico It is because you were using blockquote instead of code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You shouldn't use regex for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/965648), but regardless this will fix it:

```
if ($line =~ m|<amount>(\d*\.\d{2})\d*<//)| { $amount = $1; }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\d*\.\d{2}` regex fragment only recognize a number with exactly two decimal places. Your sample has five decimal place, and thus does not match this fragment.

You want to use `\d*\.\d+` if you need to have a least one decimal place, or `\d*\.\d{2,5}` if you can have between 2 and 5 decimal place.

And you should not use back-tick characters in your regex as they have no meaning in a regex, and thus are interpreted as regular character.

So you want to use:

```
if ($line =~ m/<amount>(\d*\.\d{2,5})<\/amount>/) { $amount = $1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a regex pattern, the sequence "{2}" means match **exactly** two instances of the preceding pattern.

So \d{2} will only match two digits, whereas your input text had five digits at that point.

If you don't want the trailing digits, then you can discard them using \d* outside the capture-parentheses.

Also, if your pattern contains slashes, consider using a different delimiter to avoid having to escape the slashes, e.g.

```
if ($line =~ m{<amount>(\d*\.\d{2})\d*</}) { $amount = $1; }
```

Also, if you want to parse XML, then you may want to consider using an XML library such as [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML).